# Is there a way to use the output from Matlab within the Eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, function, program-entry-point

As a starting point, i'll note that my java skills are extremely limited.

So far I have successfully linked projects, libraries and sources. I believe the answer to my question lies in the use of 'getter setters', although the java documents are extremely difficult to understand (the lingo).

I've seen other questions which are similar but none with the inclusion of calling Matlab functions, potentially making this a new question (as it relates only to the most up to date Matlab version). I have tried setting these up, but cannot gain access to the output.

I'm having some difficulty with sharing this information between Matlab 2017a and Eclipse. I can use Eclipse to trigger a Matlab function (My_Function. Code_1). The output can be seen on the Eclipse console, however, I cannot gain access to it in Code_2.

**Is there a way to use the output from Matlab within the Eclipse workspace?**

```
Code_1 -----
package sicktodeath;
import com.mathworks.engine.MatlabEngine;

public class Call_Mat_two {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] engines = MatlabEngine.findMatlab();
        MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.connectMatlab(engines[0]);

        // Function Input
        eng.putVariable("Input_Var", 0.00045);

        // Run function => Calls the matlab function and provides output
        eng.eval("[Function_Output]   = My_Function(Input_Var);");      

        // Function Output => I cannot access this variable from another Java main method
        double Function_Output = eng.getVariable("Function_Output");   

        hype myList = new hype();
        myList.set_Value(10);                     //set n value
        double currentN = myList.get_Value();     //get n's current value

        eng.close();
    }
}
```

OR

```
Code_2 ---
package sicktodeath;
import sickofit.Memes;

public class hype extends Call_Mat_two {

    public static double n;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //  This calls the main method which triggers the Matlab function
        Call_Mat_two.main(args);   

        System.out.println("Complete");
    }

    public double get_Value() {
        return n;
    }

    public void set_Value(double n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like [getVariable()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/com.mathworks.engine.matlabengine-class.html#bvar0qe-1) is what you need. Also, your code would be a lot more readable with less vertical whitespace.

Comment: @jsheeran I've edited well, but he have to accept it

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you want to do with Eclipse? If you just want to call Matlab from a Java program (as you're currently doing), this doesn't have to do anything with Eclipse! If you want to integrate your Matlab program into Eclipse, you'll probably have to write an Eclipse Plugin - this will require a certain proficiency in writing Java programs.

Comment: Hi sruetti, I already have access to Matlab through Eclipse. I'm aiming to use eclipse to generate an array which will be passed to the matlab engine, which will then pass some outputs back to Eclipse. The difficulty i'm having is not the connection but how to access what Matlab passes back to Eclipse. Thanks, paul

Answer (score 0):

Your comment on this line suggests you're on the right track, but that you misunderstand the structure of a Java program:

```
 double Function_Output = eng.getVariable("Function_Output"); //  I cannot access this variable from another Java main method
```

The issue seems to be in the way you're structuring your project. Your `main` method shouldn't be handling things like this, but should be delegating it to other methods or classes.

```
public class Foo {
  MatlabEngine engine;

  public Foo() {
    //get an instance of MatlabEngine, assign it to engine
    //do whatever other setup you need to do
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Foo().doStuff();
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    System.out.println(engine.getVariable("Function_Output")); // note that you haven't needed to declare engine in this method scope
  }
}
```

Do a bit of Googling and have a read about constructors, objects and instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for you answer jsheeran. I've tried running it and I get the below error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method println(boolean) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream

Comment: Seems like 'System.out.println(engine.getVariable("Function_Output"));' is empty

Comment: It's not intended as a complete, working solution - only an illustration of how you might expose your `MatlabEngine` and the variables you get from it to other parts of your program. You'll need to fill in the blanks yourself.

Comment: Hi again, this was with the Matlab engine and all of the input set-up/exception handling. Thank you for your suggestion, it's greatly appreciated. I had given up, but knowing it's possible will allow me to proceed again. Paul